# Android - Dialog animation

Tags: android, animation, dialog

I got customised Dialog popup, with simple options, like "exit". When user clicks the exit button, dialog cancels itself and calls method finish() for the activity.

My question is, how to force Activity to wait until Dialog exit animation is done, then finish the Activity.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

    dialog.dismiss();
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {

        YourActivity.this.finish();

        }
    }, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Runnable](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Runnable.html) delay your activity finish action till your dialog is not get dismiss, within `OnCancelListener` which to be set for the [Dialog.setOnCancelListener()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#setOnCancelListener%28android.content.DialogInterface.OnCancelListener%29).

Answer (score 0):

Use style with your animation for show and dissmiss

`<style name="dialog_animations">
        <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/some_anim</item>
        <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/some_anim</item>
    </style>`